# how to make the panel open when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as you can see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AH4zp/), when the page is loaded the panel still **hidden**. I want to make one of the panel **already opened** when user loaded the page. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just simulate a click on the panel you want to open on page load:

```
$("#dock li").eq(0).click(); // click first panel
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AH4zp/8/)

Comment: Definitely the easiest solution +1